# Making separate column in a dataframe after groupby function iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a very large dataframe which is like the **first four column** of this dataframe. I am trying to generate the 5th i.e. DataType column which corresponds to the datatype of the "Word" column.

*Note that datatype corresponds to "WEEKDAY", "DATE" etc. not the python datatype.*

```
Page    LineNum    Word    Line                     DataType
1        1         Today   Today is 5th Sept 2015   NULL
1        1         is      Today is 5th Sept 2015   NULL
1        1         5th     Today is 5th Sept 2015   DATE
1        1         Sept    Today is 5th Sept 2015   DATE
1        1         2015    Today is 5th Sept 2015   DATE
...
1        4         Sunday  Sunday will be Sept 8th  WEEKDAY 
1        4         will    Sunday will be Sept 8th  NULL
1        4         be      Sunday will be Sept 8th  NULL
1        4         Sept    Sunday will be Sept 8th  DATE
1        4         8th     Sunday will be Sept 8th  DATE
```

I have separate functions which extracts list of all sub-string of a particular datatype from a string. Say `isit_date` returns `['5th Sept 2015']` for Page 1 Line 1.

To get the DataType column I am using a groupby and lambda function. There are many pages and many lines.

I am trying this with the following code:

```
file_dataframe['DataType'] = 'NULL'
for name, groups in file_dataframe.groupby(['Page', 'LineNum']):
    list_of_dates = isit_date(str(groups['Line'][0]))
    groups['DataType'] = groups['Word'].apply(lambda x: "DATE" if x in list_of_dates else 'NULL')
```

I can see many faults in this. The groups won't write into the initial dataframe... but however am getting error in this code. Can someone suggest the correct and efficient approach.

**I am trying to use groupby because-
isit_date() function take some time to execute and I don't want to repeat that for every group since the Line for every group is same.**

I am using python 3 and pandas.
Please comment if there is something more I need to explain about my question.

Here is the isit_date code

```
import datetime
import datefinder as dt
from dateutil.parser import parse
from commonregex import CommonRegex


    class FindDates:

        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def isit_date(self, s):
            commonregex_object = CommonRegex(s)
            dates_list = commonregex_object.dates
            additional_dates = [x for x in s.split(" ") if len(x) == 8 and x.isdigit()]
            if len(additional_dates) > 0:
                additional_dates = [x[0:2]+"/"+x[2:4]+"/"+x[4:] for x in additional_dates]
                dates_list.extend(additional_dates)
            datefinder_dates = [w[1] for w in list(dt.find_dates(s, source=True))]
            dates_list.extend(datefinder_dates)
            return self.verify_dates(dates_list)

        @staticmethod
        def verify_dates(dates_list):
            dates_list = list(set(dates_list))
            min_year = datetime.datetime.now().year - 200
            max_year = min_year + 400
            return_date_list = []
            for each_date in dates_list:
                try:
                    dt_obj = parse(each_date)
                    if min_year <= dt_obj.year <= max_year:
                        return_date_list.append(each_date)
                except:
                    pass
            return return_date_list
```

Comment: What's the purpose of using `groupby`, can't you just have logic to determine `DataType` from `Word` + `Line` ?

Comment: What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: @jpp That will increase the running time. The function to extract different datatype takes time and I don't want to repeat it for 'Line' column since it is same for every group.

Comment: @R.A.B.B.I.T The 5th column... DataType

Comment: How looks `isit_date` function ?

Comment: @jezrael The function is too big to paste here. That function returns list of all dates in a line.

Comment: So for each group it return one item list only?

Comment: @jezrael This is the function https://pastebin.com/1QaEKCdt

Comment: @AkashKumar Given the first 5 rows you show - what is the expected output? 5 rows or 1 row?

Comment: So function return list of string like `['5th Sept 2015', 'Sept 8th']` ?

Comment: @jezrael The bigger task is that it can return multiple datatype and I will handle that as "DATE|WEEKDAY" sort of thing. For now I was stuck in this.

Comment: @AkashKumar - Hard question, especially how extract `WEEKDAY` or many different types. Need custom parser for each type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try create custom function:

```
def isit_date(x):
    return ['5th Sept 2015', 'Sept 8th']

def f(x):
    #split and flatten all values to one list of words
    list_of_dates = [y for x in isit_date(str(x['Line'].iat[0])) for y in x.split()]

    x['DataType'] = x['Word'].apply(lambda x: "DATE" if x in list_of_dates else 'NULL')
    return x

df = file_dataframe.groupby(['Page', 'LineNum']).apply(f)

print (df)
   Page  LineNum    Word                     Line DataType
0     1        1   Today   Today is 5th Sept 2015     NULL
1     1        1      is   Today is 5th Sept 2015     NULL
2     1        1     5th   Today is 5th Sept 2015     DATE
3     1        1    Sept   Today is 5th Sept 2015     DATE
4     1        1    2015   Today is 5th Sept 2015     DATE
5     1        4  Sunday  Sunday will be Sept 8th     NULL
6     1        4    will  Sunday will be Sept 8th     NULL
7     1        4      be  Sunday will be Sept 8th     NULL
8     1        4    Sept  Sunday will be Sept 8th     DATE
9     1        4     8th  Sunday will be Sept 8th     DATE
```

Comment: This will solve, but I guess this will apply the *isit_date* to everyline which is a lot more time consuming when I apply this to 100s of documents with 1000s of lines.

Comment: @AkashKumar - hmmm, so `x['Line'].iat[0]` should help here

Comment: @AkashKumar - jpp solution should be faster, so used it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found `apply` + `lambda` is often inefficient with string operations versus list comprehensions with iteration. Here's an alternative approach:

```
# define row iterator
unique_tups = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Page', 'LineNum']).itertuples()

# construct dictionary mapping page + line to set of dates
d = {(row['Page'], row['LineNum']): set(isit_date(str(row['Line']))) \
     for row in unique_tups}

# apply membership test in list comprehension
df['DateType'] = [row['Word'] in d[(row['Page'], row['LineNum'])] \
                  for row in df.itertuples()]

# use Pandas for Boolean mapping, which we know is efficient in Pandas
mapper = {True: 'Date', False: 'Null'}
df['DateType'] = df['DateType'].map(mapper)
```

Comment: d = {(row['Page'], row['LineNum']): set(isit_date(str(row['Line'][0]))) for row in unique_tups}
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @AkashKumar, Maybe remove the `[0]` index. Can't tell for sure, since you haven't shared `isit_date`.

Comment: isit_date takes string input and returns list of string.Btw Shared in the comments of question

Comment: @AkashKumar, Sorry, can't view any pastebin. Update your question with a [mcve] if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use groupby for that. You could just do:

```
df['isit_date'] = df.Line.map(isit_date)
df['DataType'] = df.apply(lambda row: "DATE" if row.Word in row.isit_date else "NULL", axis=1)
```

Comment: This may not work for OP as many items in `isit_date` are repeated. Looks like `isit_date` is the bottleneck.